# Why does the JS function stop execution after the first html element?

Tags: javascript, html, recursion

It is necessary to leave only the `li` tags.
Of the other tags, leave only the text.

My code:

```js
let html = `
<ol>
<li><a href="#"><code>foo</code> link text</a>;</li>
<li><a href="#"><code>bar</code> link text</a>;</li>
</ol>
<p>Paragraph text <code>baz</code> and <code>biz</code> text.</p>
<p>Paragraph text.</p>
`;

html = `<body>${html}</body>`;

let parsed = new DOMParser().parseFromString( html, 'text/html' );

function testFn( node  ) {

    node.childNodes.forEach( function( e ) {

        testFn( e );

        if ( e.nodeType !== Node.ELEMENT_NODE ) return;

        if ( e.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'li' ) {

            e.replaceWith( ...e.childNodes );
        }
    });
}

testFn( parsed.body );

console.log( parsed.body.innerHTML );
```

Result:

```
<li>foo link text;</li>
<li>bar link text;</li>

<p>Paragraph text <code>baz</code> and <code>biz</code> text.</p>
<p>Paragraph text.</p>
```

And I need such a result:

```
<li>foo link text;</li>
<li>bar link text;</li>

Paragraph text baz and biz text.
Paragraph text.
```

Why doesn't the function handle paragraphs?

Comment: If you debug you'll note that it never gets to your `<p>` elements. It cycles through the `<ol>` and then exits.

Answer (score 2):

`forEach()` is not ideal for conditional recursion and only adds complexity in its closure over the passed array and handling of the callback. Here is your logic transposed to a `for...of` loop.

```js
let html = `
<ol>
<li><a href="#"><code>foo</code> link text</a>;</li>
<li><a href="#"><code>bar</code> link text</a>;</li>
</ol>
<p>Paragraph text <code>baz</code> and <code>biz</code> text.</p>
<p>Paragraph text.</p>
`;

html = `<body>${html}</body>`;

let parsed = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');

function testFn(node) {
  for (const childNode of node.childNodes) {
    testFn(childNode);

    if (childNode.nodeType !== Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      continue;
    }

    if (childNode.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'li') {
      childNode.replaceWith(...childNode.childNodes);
    }    
  }
}

testFn(parsed.body);

console.log(parsed.body.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the `childNodes` while iterating over them. Use copies and it works:

```js
let html = `
<ol>
<li><a href="#"><code>foo</code> link text</a>;</li>
<li><a href="#"><code>bar</code> link text</a>;</li>
</ol>
<p>Paragraph text <code>baz</code> and <code>biz</code> text.</p>
<p>Paragraph text.</p>
`;

html = `<body>${html}</body>`;

let parsed = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');

function testFn(node) {
  [...node.childNodes].forEach(function(e) {
    testFn(e);
  });
  
  [...node.childNodes].forEach(function(e) {
    if (e.nodeType !== Node.ELEMENT_NODE) return;

    if (e.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'li') {
      e.replaceWith(...e.childNodes);
    }

  });
}

testFn(parsed.body);
console.log(parsed.body.innerHTML);
```